# Chm file freeze the application when Url or Print buttons were clicked

Tags: c#, winforms, chm

When I open help file from my Windows Forms application I'm using this code.

```
    public static void ShowHelp(string constant)
    {
        Help.ShowHelp(dummyFormForHelp.Value, CHMFile, HelpNavigator.Topic, constant);
    }
```

It works fine except when I click on GO>URL... or Print button in the help file.
[[image: 1]]

I get no messages and the app and chm file don't response at all. And I need go to task manager and kill the process. I have no idea what it is.

I tried to open the same file using the same code from the simple Windows Form application with only one form and everything was perfect. So I think something wrong in my application.

What can cause such issue?
It's a big enterprise application with a lot of screens.

Comment: does it work when you open the CHM file from shell (windows file explorer) and Go > URL? what are you passing as the `parent` (first argument to `ShowHelp(...)`? the entire host form, or a particular control?

Comment: @dlatikay I tried to add null, new Form() and main window and always get the same result. If I open chm file outside of the app everything just fine.

Comment: Have you tried to (carefully) delete the hh.dat file described at [.chm file is not programmatically accessible in SOME Folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41488501/chm-file-is-not-programmatically-accessible-in-some-folders/41661701#41661701)?

Comment: Is this your own CHM file and created by yourself?

Comment: @help-info.de Yep, it's created from docx file.

Comment: @help-info.de Deleting hh.dat didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried opening the `.chm` file from Windows Explorer? Does printing work then?

Comment: @Lasse - this was answered by Dmitriy in the second comment above "... If I open chm file outside of the app everything just fine."

Comment: Please note - answer was edited (HH_CLOSE_ALL info).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all question is not quite clear described:

- It should be mentioned that chm file is generated by [NuHelp](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nuhelp/) (it was temporary solution but we all know temporary is always permanent, huh?) )
- `dummyFormForHelp.Value` says nothing here, it is just lazy initialized instance of form to prevent topmost position of help window and allow to switch between application and help

`dummyFormForHelp.Value` means:

```c#
private static readonly Lazy<Form> dummyFormForHelp = new Lazy<Form>(() =>
{
    var form = new Form();
    form.CreateControl();
    return form;
});
```

Back to original issues with WinForms<>CHM Help:

- issues are appeared only if help is opened by application, if help is opened directly - no issues at all
- endless loop is caught in 100% when navigating to URL, Print or typing any world in Search tab

Research shows that your issue with frozen application and opened chm is not unique:

- [Bug in some versions of Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3080042/chm-file-freezes-when-you-enter-characters-in-search-box-on-the-index)
- [Issues with CHM generated by RoboHelp](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e5c9824e-8931-425a-a084-0ad408e2fa6b/windows-10-chm-files-crash-during-index-search-when-called-with-htmlhelp-api?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues)
- Topic on connect [Help.ShowHelp hangs in endless loop on Windows 10](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1892791/help-showhelp-hangs-in-endless-loop-on-windows-10) and astonishing answer: *Unfortunately, this is an issue with the Windows Help System, not Windows Forms. Connect feedback is not currently being accepted by the team that owns the Help system, so we cannot route this as a connect issue. We appreciate your report.*
- Example of stack with hang [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.helpauthoring/08qM_PIu3Bc)

**Solution**

Ways of resolving issue:

- Try the last version of [NuHelp](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nuhelp/)
- Try different converters and check if it can help
- Do not use any converter and generate help file on your own
- Start help as different process

***Start help as different process***:

hh is added to windows path, so such commands can be executed easily:

```
hh "help.chm::/topic.html"

hh "help.chm::/topic.html#subtopic"

hh -mapid 12345 help.chm
```

Drawback of workaround: each call of help from application will open new instance of help.

**EDIT: 28/08/2017**

For future readers:

- recompilation by different commonly used converters did not help
- help was recreated with Help&Manual,
- Index was returned and keywords were configured properly, Search was returned
- calling of `hh` was used

Now help works as expected.

Comment: P.S. It is funny to give an answer to co-worker on stackoveflow :-)

Comment: _First of all question is not quite clear described_ - agreed.

Answer (score 3):

The code snippet for opening the CHM seems not to be clean (??? `dummyFormForHelp.Value`, `constant`). `Help.ShowHelp()` is like a wrapper around the good old HTMLHelp API calls (see also: [HTMLHelp API - VBA, VB6 und VB2003](https://www.help-info.de/en/Help_Info_HTMLHelp/hh_api.htm)). The parameters are a bit stubborn.

A second thought - please read the [HTMLHelp API - HH_CLOSE ALL Note](https://www.help-info.de/en/Help_Info_HTMLHelp/hh_api.htm#HH_CLOSE) and crosscheck your code. Because of a bug in the HH API make sure you call this in your main form's Query_Unload event not OnClose.

Please call the `Help.ShowHelp()` function with the correct parameters as shown below.

```
Help.ShowHelp(this, CHMFile, HelpNavigator.Topic, "foobar.htm");
```

[image]

From my example app screenshot above all of the following code is working for me. Please try for your needs. Open URL is special here and not the one shown in your screenshot (URL ...).

```
#region mnuHelp ---------------------------------------------

private void mnuHelpContents_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //--- Show contents of help file.
    Help.ShowHelp(this, helpProviderMain.HelpNamespace);
}

private void mnuHelpIndex_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //--- Show index of help file.
    Help.ShowHelpIndex(this, helpProviderMain.HelpNamespace);
}

private void mnuHelpSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //--- Show search tab of help file.
    Help.ShowHelp(this, helpProviderMain.HelpNamespace, HelpNavigator.Find);
}

private void mnuHelpTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //--- Show a web site with help content.
    Help.ShowHelp(this, "http://www.stackoverflow.com");
}

private void mnuHelpOpenTopicByName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //--- Open topic by name.
    Help.ShowHelp(this, helpProviderMain.HelpNamespace, HelpNavigator.Topic, "Garden/tree.htm");
}

private void mnuHelpOpenTopicById_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //--- Open topic by ID.
    Help.ShowHelp(this, helpProviderMain.HelpNamespace, HelpNavigator.TopicId, "20010");
}

#endregion -----------------------------------------------
```

**Edit:**

Download and run [MJ's Diagnostics](https://www.help-info.de/en/far-html/far-download/#mjs-help-diagnostics) tool.

MJ's Diagnostics is a small utility that reports if all the HTML Help runtime & Workshop (compiler) DLLs are installed and registered to the correct locations.  If you have compiler crashes, and crashes when simply opening a CHM, or when searching from the CHM search tab, then this utility will help sort out rouge DLL problems.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not help, the issue is not to open chm file (which is done correctly), but why application is frozen when some actions are executed in chm (e.g. type anything in search)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug of Windows 10, and has been fixed in Windows 10, v1607/build 14393.

It was present at least in Windows 10, v1507/build 10240 and v1511/build 10586.
(I had created a [Connect issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1892791/help-showhelp-hangs-in-endless-loop-on-windows-10) for this topic, but unfortunately, the site is not accessible anymore.)